# Apply many functions to one vector

Tags: r, apply

I am looking for an option to apply many functions to one vector. I think it is kind on an inverse apply function where one function is applied to many vectors (or columns).

Is there a way of specifing two or more functions (like mean and max) and apply this on a vector?

Comment: an example could be appreciated but I guess one way is to do e.g. `v <- rnorm(10); sapply(c("mean","median","sd"), function(nf){get(nf)(v)})`

Comment: This is one solution I was looking for. Unfortunatly I wasn't familiar with the get function. Thanks solving this despite I didn't provides an example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Similar to @CathG's comment, but without `get`:

```
v <- rnorm(10)
funs <- list(mean, median, sd) 
sapply(funs, function(fun, x) fun(x), x = v)
```

Or with `do.call`:

```
sapply(funs, do.call, args = list(v))
```

Comment: Why not just `sapply(funs, function(fun, x) fun(v))`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Best practice is to always pass all objects explicitly instead of relying on scoping.